# Get Unicode from json file

Tags: c++, json, unicode, c++14

I am working on a C++ project (C++14) and I am facing the following issue. I have a JSON file with a field containing Unicode characters. I am using nlohmann/json to retrieve information from this field. However, when I retrieve it, it doesn't match my expectations. Below is my source code:

```
std::u16string Str16 = u"\u9db4\u5c4b\u516b\u5e61 \u4eac\u962a\u767e\u8ca8\u5e97\u5b88\u53e3\u5e97";//L"鶴屋八幡 京阪百貨店守口店"
std::ifstream jsonFile("name.json");

if (!jsonFile.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "can't open JSON" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

nlohmann::json jsonData;
jsonFile >> jsonData;

std::string unicodeStr = jsonData["name"];

jsonFile.close();
return 0;
```

name.json

```json
{
"name": "\u9db4\u5c4b\u516b\u5e61 \u4eac\u962a\u767e\u8ca8\u5e97\u5b88\u53e3\u5e97"
}
```

My desire is to be able to transform the Unicode string 'unicodeStr' into a 'char16_t' string or 'u16string'.
Or get unicodeStr = "\u9db4\u5c4b\u516b\u5e61 \u4eac\u962a\u767e\u8ca8\u5e97\u5b88\u53e3\u5e97"

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: You do not appear to have a json file containing unicode characters. You appear to have a json file containing ASCII text that can be interpreted as references to unicode characters.

Comment: `nlohmann::json` supports `std::u16string`. https://github.com/nlohmann/json.  And if you read into `std::string`, it stores the unicode as UTF-8.  These reinforce the idea that you don't have unicode in your file. https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: @MooingDuck Thank you for your comment. So, if I want to retrieve the string above, how can I do it? Because if I retrieve it as a std::string, it won't give me the desired result.
Expect: "鶴屋八幡 京阪百貨店守口店" but
Output: "é¶´å±‹å…«å¹¡ äº¬é˜ªç™¾è²¨åº—å®ˆå£åº—"

Comment: @Shawn sorry for the confusion

Comment: I try `std::u16string unicodeStr = jsonData["name"];` but throw exception:  `Microsoft C++ exception: nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::detail::type_error at memory location 0x0000004F734FF068. occurred `

Comment: @MooingDuck json does support Unicode escape sequences https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-7

Comment: Nlohmann doesn't support Unicode strings when reading https://github.com/nlohmann/json#character-encoding you'll need to convert from utf-8 if you want Unicode. Try https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp

Comment: @KaiAkiho: Why do you think the output is `"é¶´å±‹å…«å¹¡ äº¬é˜ªç™¾è²¨åº—å®ˆå£åº—"`?  Please add the code you used to determine that into the question. I think *that* code is where the bug is.

Comment: @AlanBirtles: (A) That link clearly shows that `Nlohmann` does indeed support unicode strings when reading.  Also, utf-8 *is* unicode.  The `u` in `utf-8` literally stands for Unicode. I suspect that `unicodeStr` is correctly reading in and holding valid utf-8, and he has a bug when rendering this to the terminal.

Comment: @MooingDuck read it carefully `std::u16string and std::u32string can be parsed, assuming UTF-16 and UTF-32 encoding, respectively. These encodings are not supported when reading from files or other input containers.` you can put `std::u16string` into a json object but you can't get it back when reading from a stream (I think, its not clear)

Comment: @MooingDuck seems like I'm right: https://godbolt.org/z/TffYePr8r

Comment: @AlanBirtles: `Only UTF-8 encoded input is supported` means that the *encoding in the file* is always UTF-8.  `The strings stored in the library are UTF-8 encoded.` means that the library uses UTF-8 for all *in-memory strings*. Therefore any interop with `std::string` will use the UTF-8 encoding.`std::u16string and std::u32string can be parsed, assuming UTF-16 and UTF-32 encoding, respectively` means that Nlohmann *can interact with those classes, and when doing so, converts the encoding.*   That being said, your link proves theres a bug in Nlohmann and its u16string support is broken :(

Comment: OH! I see! `std::u16string and std::u32string can be parsed` means the *parser* can take those as input strings, but apparently the other operations do not support those types :( https://godbolt.org/z/s6shKEnhM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine.  The problem is elsewhere.

All things in memory are just byte values.  The idea that certain patterns represent integers, floats, characters, or string, requires you to make assumptions about how you interact with that memory.  Notably, there are *hundreds* of different encodings for storing text in bytes, (9+ of these encodings have full Unicode support) and `std::string` can hold... basically all but 3 of those.

Most developers just "use the defaults", which on American versions of Windows, assumes all text is stored in the [`Windows-1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding.  Developers also assume that each "Character" is 1 `char`, which is true for `Windows-1252`, but is an incorrect assumption for many other encodings. Notably, this assumption is incorrect for *all 9+ Unicode encodings*.

However, `nlohmann` is giving you a `std::string` whose internal text encoded in UTF-8.  Therefore, when your other code attempts to use this text (such as passing it to `std::cout`), that other code is decoding the bytes as some other encoding (probably `Windows-1252`), which is resulting in `é¶´å±‹å…«å¹¡ äº¬é˜ªç™¾è²¨åº—å®ˆå£åº—`.  This is a very common bug, commonly called [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) (Note that the text in the sample image even looks virtually identical to your results)

There's generally two ways to approach this problem:

- Looks easy, actually hard: Use some library to convert the text from utf-8 to the encoding that the rest of your program is using.  Some libraries for this are [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/), [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html), or [Windows APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar). The rest of your code won't correctly handle Unicode text though.
- Looks hard, actually easy: Fix your entire program to interpret `std::string` as UTF8. [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) has helper methods for this, but Linux usually just does this by default.